# What alternative browsers are available on Android?

Tags: browser

What are the browser alternatives on Android and what are the main features that they offer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some options:

- Coco
- Dolphin
- Opera Mini
- Skyfire

Here's a quick read on [AndroidApps.org](http://www.androidapps.org/finding-the-best-android-browser) that gives overviews on some of the more popular browsers. And a longer one from [PC World](http://www.pcworld.com/article/206278/battle_of_the_android_browsers.html?tk=hp_new).

I personally just use the stock Android browser. I've used Dolphin HD for a while, but at times it felt slow (on my Droid). The Opera Mini browser is supposed to be pretty quick at loading pages because it will transfer your requests through Opera's servers first so that they can compress the content and send it back to you. Right now, I'm waiting for the release of [Fennec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_for_mobile), by Mozilla, which will hopefully be amazing.

Answer (score 5):

An alpha version of [Fennec](http://blog.mozilla.com/blog/2010/08/27/fennec-alpha-released-for-android-and-nokia-n900/) (essentially Firefox mobile) was released recently

Comment: The current versions is now beta 2 and the official download is from http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/m/beta

Answer (score 1):

[Kiwi browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser) and [Yandex browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yandex.browser&hl=en_US) are both based on Chromium and support extensions.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Xscope Browser](http://www.appbrain.com/app/xscope-browser--web--file/sui.mRelease) it offers Tabbed browsing, Download (YouTube) vids, Multi-touch, easy page sharing.

Comment: The Youtube download sounds like a good feature to have.

Answer (score 0):

Opera recently released [Opera Mobile 10.1 Beta](http://my.opera.com/operamobile/blog/opera-mobile-10-1-beta-for-android) for Android, which is a full featured browser that [renders HTML content locally](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/news/2010/11/hands-on-opera-mobile-101-beta-for-android-a-smooth-ride.ars) instead of on Opera's servers:

> Opera's phone browsers come in two
>   flavors: Mini and Mobile. The Mini
>   version, which is primarily intended
>   for feature phones, offloads much of
>   its workload to Opera's remote
>   rendering proxy. The Mobile version
>   bundles Opera's Presto rendering
>   engine and does all of the HTML
>   parsing and page rendering on the
>   device itself. Opera launched a port
>   of Mini for Android earlier this year,
>   but the new Mobile port is a welcome
>   addition for users who want the full
>   Opera experience on their Android
>   smartphone.

It is a large download and takes up to 20MB of storage, but provides a great browsing experience. I used it on my Windows Mobile based Touch Pro previously, and really liked [Opera Link](http://www.opera.com/link/) for synchronizing bookmarks between devices.